# Do chicks need to be fed?

Tags: harvest-moon-back-to-nature

Not talking about chicken, but chicks. There is a difference between those.

When they are hatched, do they need to be fed?

Comment: I can't speak for this exact game, but in all other Harvest Moons I've played, chicks don't need food.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back to Nature is one of my favorite Harvest Moon games, and easily the one I've played the most.

I can therefore say with confidence that newly hatched chicks do not need to be fed.